# Object keys and values not returned in the correct order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a function on line 76 called `getActivityData` in which I create an object, the keys of which are dates in milliseconds, and their values are integers. The loop goes over a specified period (this happens in `App`) and checks how many tasks were completed during that period. I need to create two arrays, one for the object's keys, one for values, and keep their exact order. However when I use `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`, the order is altered, it seems that it gets reversed except for the last value/key. Editor link https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntdk3g?file=src%2FApp.js
Here's what the object looks like (last five days + today)

```
{
1686034800000: 0,
1686121200000: 0,
1686207600000: 0,
1686294000000: 0,
1686380400000: 1,
1686466800000: 0
}
```

This is what `Object.values()` returns

```
{
0: "1686380400000",
1: "1686294000000",
2: "1686207600000",
3: "1686121200000",
4: "1686034800000",
5: "1686466800000"
}
```

And `Object.keys()` returns this

```
{
0: 1,
1: 0,
2: 0,
3: 0,
4: 0,
5: 0
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` and other similar facilities iterate through properties on objects in a way defined by the spec. In this case, your property names are numbers (integers), and the runtime always iterates through those in numeric (ascending) order.

Comment: @Pointy but this has never been an issue, I've tested this in jsfiddle and everything is returned correctly, what gives? https://jsfiddle.net/Montinyek/3yv0sLpk/

Comment: in that example the numeric keys start off in the order that the runtime will impose, so nothing changes. If you scramble the object in that example, you will see the same behavior.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to rely on the order?

Comment: are you handling the array in react/redux ?

Comment: You have the outputs of `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` reversed, and they don't return plain objects, but arrays.

Comment: If want to have items in order of insertion use `Map` or an array

Comment: @Pointy but the object in my original example is in the same order as the one in the fiddle

Comment: @Konrad, they are in insertion order (keys represent integers that are too large to be considered indices to be sorted numerically).

Comment: @trincot I'm console logging them starting at line 88 before reversing them, right now I'm just trying to get the right output in the console

Comment: @trincot the MDN article is a little vague; I assume you're saying that the values need to fit in 32 bits (or 31 or whatever)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying, and the ECMAScript specs are unambiguous on that.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator yes I'm doing this in React

Comment: @Qaqli, a link can be interesting, but your question would have needed the minimal(!) code to reproduce the problem. What is certain, is that your keys will be ordered in the order that they were inserted, so check your insertion order.

Comment: @trincot that might be the problem then, since the keys are inserted in descending order

Comment: One trick could be to use keys that don't have the rightmost three zeroes (divide by 1000, apparently you only have multiples of 1000), and then they fall in the 32bit range and will be forced into their numerical order. But taking a step back, it is considered bad practice to rely on order when you have a plain object. For order you should use an array (of pairs or of objects).

Comment: i would keep it simple and use a Map